# How to get X and Y coordinates of a component in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS, therefore, if there is something wrong or naive in this question then I'm sorry about that and please suggest me where I'm wrong.

I want to render multiple components at once, but want the window to initially focus on a specific component.

I want to render the component "RenderCells" multiple times at once, with different props:

```
export default function Calendar() {
    const calendarCells = [];

    let startDate = new Date(2010, 0, 1);

    for (let i = 2010; i < 2030; i++) {
        let nextYear = addYears(startDate, 1);
        for (let j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
            calendarCells.push(
               <div className="calendar" key={`${j}${i}`}>
                  // This component needs to be rendered multiple times, with different props.
                  <RenderCells renderDate={startDate} />
               </div>
            );
            startDate = addMonths(startDate, 1);
         }
         startDate = nextYear;
      }

    return (
      <>
        {calendarCells}
      </>
    );
}
```

And now in the "RenderCells" component when a case is satisfied, I want the coordinate of this particular component, so that I can move my window object to focus on this component:

```
export default function RenderCells({ renderDate }) {
   if (currentDate.getMonth() === renderDate.getMonth() && currentDate.getYear() === renderDate.getYear()) {
        
        // get coordinates of this component here.
        const {X_coordinate, Y_coordinate} = some_method();
        
        // moving window focus to new coordinates.
        window.moveTo(X_coordinate, Y_coordinate);
   }
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: `window.moveTo()` would move the browser window on-screen (though modern browsers tend to disallow that API). What is your end goal here? I doubt it's moving the window.

Comment: The end goal is to basically focus my screen (when the app starts) on that component, I didn't know if there is any other way to do that, by some googling I found this therefore, used that method here.

Comment: You can get a reference to an element you want to focus to, and then when those conditions are satisfied, call `elementRef.current.scrollIntoView()`

Comment: Right, so you mean you want to scroll the window, not move the window :)